# Print timestamp with 2 digit seconds in Jackson code

Tags: java, jackson

This Jackson code prints “2020-01-26T12:21:34.223” and I need to print only two digit seconds “34” without the decimals. How to achieve that?

```
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    om.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    om.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("ldt", ldt);
    String json = om.writeValueAsString(ldt);
    System.out.println(json);
```

Comment: What if you call the constructor of `SimpleDateFormat` with `"ss"`?

Comment: I need the full time stamp without the seconds decimals

Comment: Look at the code for method `toString()` in class `LocalDateTime` to understand why you are getting the value that you are getting. Then consider converting your `LocalDateTime` instance to a string using [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and write that value to your JSON string.

Comment: You can add custom serializer @ps0604

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can add `withNano(0)` to `LocalDateTime.now()`**

> `LocalDateTime.now().withNano(0);`

**Your code is as follows (Just one line has changed):**

```
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    om.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    om.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));

    //withNano(0) added
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now().withNano(0); 

    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("ldt", ldt);
    String json = om.writeValueAsString(ldt);
    System.out.println(json);
```

**Result**

2020-01-26T21:33:53

Comment: This works, but is there a way to change the format in `SimpleDateFormat` to print only the seconds without the decimals?

Answer (score 1):

1. You will have to use an `addSerializer()` call instead of `addDeserializer()`.
2. Also, you will have to truncate the `LocalDateTime` instance to seconds.
3. There seems to be no need to set the date format on the `ObjectMapper` instance.

Please have a look at the code below.

```
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    JavaTimeModule jtm = new JavaTimeModule();
    jtm.addSerializer( LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeSerializer( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME ) );
    om.registerModule( jtm );
    //om.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS );
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("ldt", ldt);
    String json = om.writeValueAsString(ldt);
    System.out.println(json);
```